# Why does this binary math fail when adding 00000001, but work correctly otherwise?

Tags: math, arduino, binary, addition

I've tried everything I can think of and cannot seem to get the below binary math logic to work. Not sure why this is failing but probably indicates my misunderstanding of binary math or C. The ultimate intent is to store large integers (unsigned long) directly to an 8-bit FRAM memory module as 4-byte words so that a micro-controller (Arduino) can recover the values after a power failure. Thus the unsigned long has to be assembled from its four byte words parts as it's pulled from memory, and the arithmetic of assembling these word bytes is not working correctly.

In the below snippet of code, the long value is defined as four bytes A, B, C, and D (simulating being pulled form four 8-bit memory blocks), which get translated to decimal notation to be used as an unsigned long in the arrangement DDDDDDDDCCCCCCCCBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAA. If A < 256 and B, C, D all == 0, the math works correctly. The math also works correctly for any values of B, C, and D if A == 0. *But* if B, C, or D > 0 and A == 1, the 1 value of A is not added during the arithmetic. A value of 2 works, but not a value of 1. Is there any reason for this? Or am I doing binary math wrong? Is this a known issue that needs a workaround?

```cpp
// ---- FUNCTIONS

unsigned long fourByte_word_toDecimal(uint8_t byte0 = B00000000, uint8_t byte1 = B00000000, uint8_t byte2 = B00000000, uint8_t byte3 = B00000000){
  return (byte0 + (byte1 * 256) + (byte2 * pow(256, 2)) + (byte3 * pow(256, 3)));
}

// ---- MAIN
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  uint8_t addressAval = B00000001;
  uint8_t addressBval = B00000001;
  uint8_t addressCval = B00000001;
  uint8_t addressDval = B00000001;

  uint8_t addressValArray[4];
  addressValArray[0] = addressAval;
  addressValArray[1] = addressBval;
  addressValArray[2] = addressCval;
  addressValArray[3] = addressDval;

  unsigned long decimalVal = fourByte_word_toDecimal(addressValArray[0], addressValArray[1], addressValArray[2], addressValArray[3]);

  // Print out resulting decimal value
  Serial.println(decimalVal);

}
```

In the code above, the binary value should result as 00000001000000010000000100000001, AKA a decimal value of 16843009. *But the code evaluates the decimal value to 16843008.* Changing the value of addressAval to 00000000 also evaluates (correctly) to 16843008, and changing addressAval to 00000010 also correctly evaluates to 16843010.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for integer arithmetic, such as square and cube. You might need `long long` for **square** but that might not be enough for **cube**.

Comment: Have you considered casting the array instead of using math?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `pow()`. This is causing everything to be calculated as a binary32, which doesn't have enough precision to hold 16843009.

```
>>> numpy.float32(16843009)
16843008.0
```

The fix is to use integers, specifically 65536 and 16777216UL.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `pow()` for this.

The usual way to do this is with the shift operator:

```
uint32_t result = uint32_t(byte3 << 24 | byte2 << 16 | byte1 << 8 | byte0);
```